# Write and Read multiple arrays on a file in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, file-io, read-write

I need to write multiple arrays (3,3) on the same file and read them one by one.
It’s the first time I use Python. Help me, please

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.savez`:

```
# save three arrays to a numpy archive file
a0 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a1 = np.array([[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]])
a2 = np.array([[21,22,23],[24,25,26],[27,28,29]])

np.savez("my_archive.npz", soil=a0, crust=a1, bedrock=a2)

# opening the archive and accessing each array by name
with np.load("my_archive.npz") as my_archive_file:
    out0 = my_archive_file["soil"]
    out1 = my_archive_file["crust"]
    out2 = my_archive_file["bedrock"]
```

https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module5_OddsAndEnds/WorkingWithFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

if you mean an array like this

```
mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

the n the solution is like this

```
with open("fout.txt", "w") as fout:
print(*mylist, sep="\n", file=fout)
```

to read like this

```
with open("fout.txt", "r") as fout:
print(fout.read())
```

Comment: Thanks but in this way I read it as a string but I need to read it as numpy array to reuse it in other mathematical operations

Comment: you can simply covert it to nupy array after reading it like that: np_array =np.array(A)